# Custom value for formControlName

Tags: angular, forms, angular2-formbuilder

I need to fill a form control with an item chosen among many. Because of the high number of options, I preferred a modal to a simple `<select>`.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <label>Item</label>
    <input formControlName="item" [readOnly]="true" (click)="showModal()"></input>    
</form>
```

The modal is able to display the available items, let the user select one of them, and update the `form.item` property accordingly.
However, because the selected item is a complex object (and not a simple string), my form display an ugly `[Object object]`. How can I tell the form to show a specific property of item?

---

This is the object I'm trying to display:

```
export class Item {
    id: number;
    owner: string;
    description: string;
}
```

I'd like to show the property `description` of the object.

Comment: Can you please offer more details ? and of course your json object

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should do something like this:

```
 <input formControlName="item" placeholder="form.controls['item'].value.description" [readOnly]="true" (click)="showModal()"></input>
```

or try to print out your object and see what's in it

```
{{form.controls['item'].value | json}}
```

or

```
{{form.controls['item'].value.description}}
```

Comment: Will it crash if the child value (description) is null on the item object? & can you prevent it from erroring with an if stmt?

Comment: @Grant You can Use the ? operator like this:  {{form.controls['item'].value?.description?}}  this makes the property optional so will  not throw any exception when null or undefined